# If condition explanation AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I found this code online. But I'm not completely sure what it means. It's to create a bouncing ball. Im just not sure whats saying in this if condition.

is it about the speed of the object or the where it's going to appear in the stage? Could u please add a //comment for a brief explanation. Thank you in advance!

```
        if ( this.x >= nStageWidth - 10 )
        {
            this.x = nStageWidth - 10;
            nSpeedX *= -1;
        }
        else if ( this.x <= 10 )
        {
            this.x = 10;
            nSpeedX *= -1;
        }

        if ( this.y >= nStageHeight - 10 )
        {
            this.y = nStageHeight - 10;
            nSpeedY *= -1;
        }
        else if ( this.y <= 10 )
        {
            this.y = 10;
            nSpeedY *= -1;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code checks the `x` or `y` property of an object to make sure it's within certain boundaries. If it's not, the object's `nSpeedX` or `nSpeedY` property is multiplied by -1.

> For example, if `x` is less than 10 or greater than or equal to
>   `nStageWidth-10`, `nSpeedX` is multiplied by -1, which I assume sends
>   the object traveling in the opposite direction.

Without more code, I can't give you the exact implementation. However, based on how everything's named, my guess is that this code sends an object bouncing from one side of the stage to the other (with 10 pixels of padding on either side).

Comment: I forgot to mention about it bouncing around the stage. Thank you!